# Unity How to hide Sprite with mask/scrollview

Tags: unity-game-engine, uiscrollview

Can someone help me.
I want to hide the fish, it's not ui image
I used rigging bonse to create the animation
Now mask doesn't work with it

I think mask/scrollview is not supported but what should I do if I want to hide it?
please someone help me. It's been 4 days and I haven't found a solution

link video: https://youtu.be/JgYsDeaRlko

Unity - How to hide Sprite with mask/scrollview

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The mask of the scroll view only affect UI elements. Sprites aren't UI components.
There is a component, Sprite Mask, to mask only sprite renderer objects.
Maybe you want to check it. Create a new object sprite mask, put a square as a sprite and resize of the same size of the scroll view.
Then, you need to set in each sprite the option mask interaction. Also in viewport disable the mask.